Why is WebAssembly execution not notably faster than JavaScript execution?
I stumbled upon this interesting speed comparison of JavaScript and WebAssembly:
enter image description here
I wondered why the difference in speed is relatively low, I expected the speed difference to be in magnitude of hundreds. Doing the FFT (Fast-Fourier-Transform) algorithm the JavaScript code even seems to execute faster.
Other tests found on the web show similar results, many result in JavaScript and WebAssembly executing at roughly the same speed.
I am very surprised by this! Why wouldn't code which is basically already machine code run magnitudes faster than JavaScript code, which has to be interpreted at runtime?

JS is compiled to machine code too by a JIT compiler

"Average" in the context of execution speed sounds nonsense.

"JavaScript code, which has to be interpreted at runtime": what is your source for this claim?

That picture says AssemblyScript, not WebAssembly.
